# Properly returning nested state with Object.assign

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm working on a React/Redux application and for the most part, everything has been working smoothly.

Essentially, it's a todo application that has categorization built in.

I'm having trouble properly returning the full existing state in my reducer when the user adds a todo-item inside a category.

The redux state before I dispatch the ADD_ITEM action looks like this:

```
{
items: {
    "HOME": [["Do laundry", "High Priority"],["Feed kids", "Low priority"] ],
    "WORK": [["Get promotion", "High priority"],["Finish project", "Medium priority"] ],
    "BOTH": [["Eat better", "Medium priority"],["Go for a run", "High priority"] ],

},
settings: {
    Test: "test"
}
}
```

The user navigates to a category(pre-made, haven't implemented creating them yet) and can create a new todo-item with a name and a priority. This dispatches an action that returns an array like [category, name, priority].

Currently in my reducer, I have it where it is successfully adding the item, but it is emptying/overwriting all the existing categories.

My reducer looks like this:

```
case types.ADD_ITEM:
let cat = action.payload[0];
let name = action.payload[1];
let priority = action.payload[2];
return Object.assign({}, state, { items: { [cat]:   [...state.items[cat], [name, priority]]}});
```

I've tried creating a new object first with all the combined items like so:

```
let combinedItems = Object.assign({}, state.items, { [cat]: [...state.items[cat], action.payload] });
```

If I console.log the above combinedItems, I get the exact object that I want items to be. However, I'm struggling to have the final object returned by the reducer to reflect that.

When I tried something like below, I got an object that contained combinedItems as a separate key inside items.

```
        return Object.assign({}, state, { items: { combinedItems, [cat]: [...state.items[cat], [name, priority]]}});
```

Can anyone help me get my final redux state to contain all the existing categories/items + the user added one? I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: You say your initial state has keys `todos` and `settings` but later you're using `items` and `settings` is gone... what's actually happening?

Comment: `Object.assign` does not do do a deep extend.

Comment: @azium: Apologies. I had changed some names right before I posted this and it was a leftover from the previous. Should be correct now.

Comment: @Bergi: What should I do instead? I've considered refactoring to have items be an array instead of an object and then store the category name as the first item in the array, but I do like the idea of the named keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use objects in places where you have arrays. In your action payload, instead of:

```
[category, name, priority]
```

You can have:

```
{category, name, priority}
action.payload.category
```

I would make the same change with your todo items. Instead of:

```
[["Eat better", "Medium priority"], ... ]
```

You can have:

```
[{ name: "Eat better", priority: "Medium" }, ... ]
```

Now in terms of whether it's better to make `items` an object with category keys or an array of items that know its category... well I think the latter is better, that way if you get a single item, you don't need to go up to its parent to find out which category it belongs to. It would also make your problem a bit more manageable.

```
items: [
  { 
    name: "Eat better", 
    priority: "Medium", 
    category: "Both" 
  }, ... 
]
```

Putting this all together to solve your problem:

```
case types.ADD_ITEM:
  let newItem = {
    name: action.payload.name,
    priority: action.payload.priority,
    category: action.payload.category
  }
  return Object.assign({}, state, { items: [ ...state.items, newItem ] })
```

Whatever benefit you had before with categories as keys are trivial to reproduce with this structure.

Get all items in the `HOME` category:

```
this.props.items.filter(item => item.category === 'HOME')
```

Comment: If you *really* want to keep your `items` structure, let me know and I'll update my answer to use it, though I highly recommend my current approach.

Comment: This looks really great. I'm going to implement it into my project right now and I'll let you know how it goes. Have to refactor a few other spots to account for the new object structure. Thank you!!

Comment: I got it all implemented and it's working great! I really appreciate you helping me solve that issue. This will be a very big help when I move on to creating the categories and stuff too. Thanks for the good ideas.